# Navigation drop-down menu not working in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The drop-down menu is not working for mobile view. When I click the services the sub-menu does not work and none of the links work either. Can anyone help me?

Please find the link to the website here: https://srikaliastrologer.com

Find a screenshot of what I see here: http://prntscr.com/ng2tj8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change css from `position: static;  to position: relative;` in below class in media query, so it will be clickable.

When you click on submenu then it will click on parent due to static position and z-index not applying and redirect so change position relative

> Z-index only works on positioned elements. A positioned elements is an
>   element whose position value is either set to absolute, fixed,
>   relative, or sticky. That is, the element has to be set to any
>   position value other than static, which is the default position value.

```
@media (max-width: 979px){
{
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    display: none;
    float: none;
    max-width: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is causing because of 'dropdown-backdrop' element which is inside that dropdown. is there any specific reason to keep that element?

That element has position fixed and higher z-index which is the main reason of causing this issue.